# Not able to see connected usb device in registry

Tags: c#, serial-port, regedit, device-manager

I have a device connected to a USB serial port which can be seen in device manager but not in registry.

When I use `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` (I am expecting to return all the connected serial ports), it is not returning all the ports from the connected device.

But after re-enabling the port I can see my desired device working and it is gone after restarting the machine.

Updating the drivers didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WMI Code Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) from Microsoft to build a query for [Win32_SerialPort](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-serialport)-Devices or maybe [Win32_PnPEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-pnpentity).

I also got problems with the SerialPort.GetPortNames() in the past, but the Win32-classes worked just fine evertime so far.